# jquery works in html but not in twig template

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

The following code will get and post the geo cordinates, but I want it to then show some text or button or something in the div.  This same code works in html, but in the twig template nothing is shown in the

```
   {%extends "LoginLogBundle:Default:index.html.twig"%}

   {%block javascripts%} 

   {{parent()}}

   <script src={{asset('js/jquery.form.js')}}></script>

   <script> 

   function getCoordPosition() { 

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{path('login_log_location')}}",
        data: {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
        },
        success: function () {
            $("#divputinarea").html('popojpojoojpopjopjojp');
        }
       });
   });
  }
return false;
 }

 </script> 

{%endblock%}

{% block body%}


 <div id="divputinarea">
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" onclick="getCoordPosition()">Click to
share     your location</button>
</div>

{%endblock%}
```

At first I thought as it's $("#divputinarea").html this would not get pickup by html.twig , Any ideas why it doesn't work in twig please ?

Comment: Is your script `js/jquery.form.js` in `web` dir?

Comment: Did you dump (`php app/console assetic:dump`) your assetic? Or you can try install assets (ex for dev env: `php app/console assets:install --symlink web/`).

Comment: @victor yes it is, some of the jquery works ie the geo part.  but not as mentioned populating the div

Comment: @NHG it works for first part, so must have the jquery available

Comment: @GAV so, maybe jQuery is included after your script? Could you check your output document head section? Or even better console output: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console?hl=en#errors_and_warnings

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery ready function to execute code after page is loaded and be sure you set {%block javascripts%} 
before the body in the base page (by default it's after)

Comment: Bizarre I found the solution which works, though quite why I don't know.  if I add "return $this->render('LoginLogBundle:Default:geo.html.twig',(array('id'=>'something'))); " in the controller I first post to  'login_log_location' it seems to work.  The id=> something isn't even used.